# Two level namespacing in Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces, rails-activerecord

If I have something like this in my Rails `model`  How are these two different?

```
class A::B::C < ApplicationRecord
  ....
end
```

```
module A
  module B
    class C < ApplicationRecord
    ....
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

Both of them are same.

```
module A
  module B
    class C 
        def test
         puts "hii"
        end
    end
  end
end

ob = A::B::C.new()
ob.test  => hi

class A::B::C
  def testing
    puts "hello"
  end
end

ob1 = A::B::C.new()
ob1.testing  => hello
```

hope it will clear the concept..